# Joomla database error after file move

Tags: sql, database, joomla

I needed to remake a site. I am relatively new to web design. I moved all the existing Joomla files to a backup folder (a very stupid move), and started to build the new page. Of course I then realized that I do not have the information from the previous site, so I tried putting all the files back, but now, of course, the site doesn't work and gives a "`Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to MySQL`" error.

I cannot access the database either, because the previous developer left no passwords. Obviously I can access the ftp.

Is there something I can do to restore the site ?

Answer (score 0):

Change database information in `configuration.php` root of the site.
check these variables-

```
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'root';//database user
public $password = '';//database password
public $db = 'database';//datebase name
public $dbprefix = 'jos_';//table prefix
public $log_path = 'E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\joomla\\logs';//log folder path
public $tmp_path = 'E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\joomla\\tmp';//tmp folder path
```

Comment: Everything seems to be in order, but still still does not work :( http://sasazlatnalasta.ba/

Comment: @Elixan:Are you able to connect database using simple php script with same database info you have in configuration.php?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm not good with php :/ I tried using the details to access the database manually though phpmyadmin, but it didn't work, which is weird...

Comment: @Elixan:So the reason is your db info is not correct.get the correct info and put in configuration.php